# How should we represent the thrusters on an AUV?

Tags: urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're looking to run ROS on an in-house AUV while hopefully bring more support in ROS for AUVs. While we could just use topics to transport thruster information between our device driver and controller using a specialized topics, I'd like to find a better approach. Our nodes consist of a thruster driver, a controller, and a thruster mapper which converts Wrenches to thruster efforts. I'd like for the mapper to be entirely generic, and somehow retrieve the names, positions, orientations, min/max thrust, etc of the thrusters relative to the vehicle's center of mass, then publish a generic thruster effort message that is compatible with thruster drivers besides our own.

It seems like there are a lot of parallels to URDF and joints in a ground vehicle. Could URDF be extended to support thrusters? What would it take to accomplish this, and would it potentially be merged into a future ros release?

It also seems like this could be done in terms of tf static transforms, one for each thrusters. Would this be a better approach instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45932/how-should-we-represent-the-thrusters-on-an-auv?/) by [matthewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3379/matthewbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen the [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) package? There might be stuff there you can use.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1